# Log inequalities and asymptotic expansions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, inequality, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm dealing with the probabilistic method and how it applies to distinct sums. In the notes I'm using I encounter the following inequality:

$2^k\le nk$, which the notes simplify into this form:

$k\le \log_2n +\log_2\log_2n + O(1)$, and I have no idea how this is arrived at.

Clearly taking a $\log_2$ on both sides gives $\log_2 2^k\le \log_2 nk \implies k\le \log_2 n +\log_2 k$

But how do we get from $\log_2k$ to $\log_2\log_2n + O(1)$?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the notes?

Comment: @Phicar Sorry for the long link, it's section 4.6 here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-218-probabilistic-method-in-combinatorics-spring-2019/lecture-notes/MIT18_218S19_full_notes.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiJw8XUrf3tAhX_TxUIHdNdDpcQFjABegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1X_6s48gFOI7v4KGVHZS21

Comment: No worries, nice notes :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the $\log_2$ of the initial inequality:
$$
k \le \log _2 n + \log _2 k.
$$
Taking the $\log_2$ again gives
$$
\log _2 k \le \log _2 (\log _2 n + \log _2 k) = \log _2 \log _2 n + \log _2 \left( {1 + \frac{{\log _2 k}}{{\log _2 n}}} \right).
$$
Substituting this back into the first inequality gives
$$
k \le \log _2 n + \log _2 \log _2 n + \log _2 \left( {1 + \frac{{\log _2 k}}{{\log _2 n}}} \right).
$$
Thus, it remains to show that the last term is $\mathcal{O}(1)$. But
$$
k \le \log _2 n + \log _2 k \le \log _2 n + \frac{k}{2} \Rightarrow k \le 2\log _2 n \Rightarrow \log _2 k \le 2\log _2 n
$$
whenever $k\geq 4$, and for $k=1,2,3$ the statement is obvious.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much